# Cannot display SVG used by <object> in browser

Tags: html, svg, web

I'm trying to set up the vector web application on my server `https://vector.cnjabber.net/` , but I've found that the SVG used by `<object>` (I think they're generated by javascripts.) cannot be displayed in browser. However, the official app at https://riot.im displays all the SVG files correctly. I made a small test on my server:

`https://cnjabber.net/test/index.html`

I use `<img src="..."/>` and `<object type="svg+xml" data="..."></object>` to use an svg file, but the browser only shows the `<img src="...">` image, the Firefox's Developer tool only says "Could not load the image". Chromium and Qupzilla also fail to load it. If I open the html file locally with file:///some/path/index.html, it works fine.

I've searched on the web, and checked I have set up the MIME type correctly in lighttpd. Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Which MIME type did you use?

Answer (score 2):

I finally know what had happened. This time I use the console in Firefox developer tools.[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgGz3.png) And I found that it's `X-Frame-Options: DENY` that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may lie with `type="xvg+xml"` which should be `type="image/svg+xml"`
Also, it should be structured like this:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" src="yourimage.svg">
    <img src="yourfallbackimage.png" alt="Your browser does not support SVG"/>
</object>
```

If the SVG is static (not interactive) then you can simply use the img tag and it should load the image fine:

```
<img src="yourimage.svg"/>
```

Comment: Oh, just a typo in my question. Well, you can go to https://vector.cnjabber.net to log in as guest, and you can see the details.

Comment: I finally know what had happened to my server (I've posted the answer.), and now it's another question that how to secure the HTTPS as well as enable SVGs loading.